# How to uninstall twilio-cli from Mac osx using brew

Tags: macos, twilio, homebrew, homebrew-cask, twilio-cli

I am on Mac os and could get twilio-cli. I have installed it using brew.

I tried

```
brew uninstall twilio 
brew remove twilio
```

It gives below error

```
    Warning: Twilio is switching the default branch from 'master' to 'main'
    Warning: requiring an update to the default homebrew tap.
    Warning: 
    Error: To upgrade twilio-cli, retap it with:
        brew untap twilio/brew
        brew tap twilio/brew
        brew upgrade twilio
```

I applied above suggested commands but it still give same error over and over again.

Answer (score 10):

Try this first

`brew update-reset $(brew --repo twilio/brew)`

Then try

`brew uninstall twilio`

`brew untap twilio/brew`

`brew tap twilio/brew`

`brew install twilio`

---

If that fails, then I would go to the folder
`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/twilio/`

and manually delete the hombrew-brew folder `rm -rf homebrew brew`

Then I would do `brew tap twilio/brew && brew install twilio`

After that you might as well run `brew update && brew upgrade`
then `brew doctor` to make sure everything is good

Comment: Thanks `brew update-reset $(brew --repo twilio/brew)` worked

Comment: Possible typo in the rm -rf command here? My folder was called homebrew-brew.

Answer (score 0):

`brew install twilio/brew/twilio` should be enough.